# Can I change my display name from the mobile site?

Tags: support, mobile-web, display-names

I want to change my display name.

Is this possible to do that from a mobile device? Do I have restricted settings if I'm using a mobile rather than PC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. But on mobile it is a little hard. You can't edit it from the mobile website directly, since the page hasn't been build for the mobile web UI. You have to go to the main site to edit your profile.

You can do that by going to the edit page directly: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current. This will land you on the page you need. It isn't really comfortable on a small device, but it will do the job.

Comment: I changed my display and saved preference.